# Calculating speed in Mbps based on known filesize and time

Tags: javascript, math

I'm having a challenging time working out a formulae to give Megabits per Second as a result.

I have the following information:

> Filesize: 1024 Bytes (and time taken in milliseconds.)
>
> E.g 1024 Bytes took 27 Milliseconds.

What is the result in Mbps?

I need something to put into a variable like: var mbps = (formulae)

Comment: so how do you convert milliseconds to seconds? How do you convert Bytes to Mb?

Comment: What formulas have you tried so far?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read [ask]. Key phrases: "Search, and research" and "Explain ... any difficulties that have prevented you from solving it yourself". Stack Overflow is not a code-writing service (although I'm sure by the time I've finished writing this comment someone will have answered this question).

Answer (score 1):

Note [Mbps to MB/s Converter](https://www.gbmb.org/mbps-to-mbs)

> 1 megabit  = 0.125 megabytes
>
> 1 megabit/second = 0.125 megabytes/second
>
> 1 Mbps = 0.125 MB/s

---

According to How to [Calculate Mbps](https://www.techwalla.com/articles/how-to-calculate-mbps)

> Step 1
>
> Express the size of the computer file in bytes.

`1024`

> Step 2
>
> Multiply the file's number of bytes by eight to find the number of
>   bits.

`1024 * 8 = 8192`

> Step 3
>
> Divide the number of bits transferred by the elapsed time, in seconds,
>   it takes to transfer the file.

`8192 / (1/Math.pow(10, 3)) * 27 = 303407.4074074074`

> Step 4
>
> Express the speed as Mbps by dividing bps by 1,000,000.

`303407.4074074074 / Math.pow(10, 6) = 0.3034074074074074`

```js
var filesize = 1024;
var Mbps = (filesize * 8 / ((1 / Math.pow(10, 3)) * 27)) / Math.pow(10, 6);

console.log(Mbps);
```